# Tokenization settings in Salesforce marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, encryption, platform-encryption

I am having encrypted data in SFDC stored and using encryption/decryption gateway(cipher cloud) i am using the data to be transferred to marketing cloud, Using the tokenized setting , Email field will be used to get the data against that field from salescloud to marketing cloud,
what settings needs to be done in Salesforce marketing side ? Kindly help with screenshot ,

Thanking you!